# What type/topology of SMPS is this?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm researching designs for a simple bipolar output switching power supply and came across the design below in a ST datasheet for the MC34063A.
[image: Dual-output MC34063 SMPS]

However, there isn't enough information in the datasheet for me to implement this design and I couldn't find any SMPS topologies in other resources that looked to be equivalent.  I was hoping someone would recognize the topology so that I could find more information on it.

On a related note, are there any other/better designs using the MC34063A (since I have a bunch on hand) for producing +/-7V @ 100mA from a 3V input?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a variant of a [flyback converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter) based around a center-tapped transformer. (Here's an [example](http://electronictheory.blogspot.com/2013/07/flyback-converter-circuit-diagram.html) from another site.) Some things that identify it as a flyback are:

1. The switch is connected directly to the transformer. This indicates an isolated/off-line converter.
2. There's no freewheeling diode on the input side of the transformer (or any freewheeling diode at all, for that matter). That says it's a flyback.
3. There are multiple output voltages, which is common for a flyback. This is done by having multiple windings on the transformer.

If the drawing were more detailed, it would show opposite-polarity dots on the two sides of the transformer, which would be another giveaway.

If you build this circuit, you will probably want to buy a transformer designed for flyback converters.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the full bridge rectifier was throwing me off.  Do you have any suggestions for resources that would help me pick the proper components for this circuit?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. I don't have any experience building isolated converters. Other companies also make MC34063s (with possibly more helpful datasheets), but I didn't find any others that had this circuit. It sounds like you're looking for something simple, and I wouldn't call flyback converters simple.

I think separate boost and buck-boost stages would work better. It would be easier to find reference circuits, and unlike this circuit both voltages would be properly regulated.